# System.Diagnostics.Process WaitForExit doesnt kill the process on timeout

Tags: c#

I run `7-zip` from my c# code:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = zipFileExePath,
    Arguments = "x \"" + zipPath + "\" -o\"" + extractPath + "\""
};

using (Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
{
    if (process.WaitForExit(timeout))
    {
    }
    else
    {
        s_logger.ErrorFormat("Timeout whilte extracting extracting {0}", zipPath);
    }

    process.Close();
}
```

Now what I see happening is that when the timeout hits, still the `7-zip` process exists in `Task Manager`. Why is that happening? I put both close and dispose

Comment: Neither Close nor Dispose will **kill** the process, it will only release the handle you have giving you access to the process. If you want to kill it, call `process.Kill();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question mentions three methods on the [Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7) class:

- [WaitForExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.7)
- [Close](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.close?view=netframework-4.7)
- [Dispose](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.dispose?view=netframework-4.7)

None of those methods will do anything to the process, certainly not kill it.

WaitForExit is an observational method, it will wait and see if the process terminates by itself. The overload with the timeout will return a `bool` telling you whether the method observed that the process terminated or not. If it didn't, it's presumably still running.

Close and Dispose does nothing to or for the process that is running, it merely closes the *handle* you have internally in the Process class that is the mechanism for how that class can keep tabs of the process in question.

It's a good idea to close this handle when you're done observing the running process.

However, if you want the process to terminate, you will have to call [Process.Kill](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.kill?view=netframework-4.7).

Comment: So has I see it whenever you use WaitForExit you should kill the process in case of timeout, otherwise it can hang

Comment: Or it could just take more time than you allowed for, none of the methods on Process can tell you that the process is hanging, you will have to find a different way of detecting that.

Comment: Note, that `Process.Kill()` kills only process, for which it is called, not spawned child processes (if such have been spawned). Since .Net 5.0 (.Net Core 3.0) `.Kill(bool)` is present, which solves this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    FileName = zipFileExePath,
    Arguments = "x \"" + zipPath + "\" -o\"" + extractPath + "\""
};

using (Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
{
    if (process.WaitForExit(timeout))
    {
        //somecode?
    }
    else
    {
        s_logger.ErrorFormat("Timeout whilte extracting extracting {0}", zipPath);
    }

    process.Kill();
}
```